# VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when trying to assign values to a range

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, vba7

I am not sure why I am getting this error when trying to run the code below

```
Sub introtocollection()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 2))
    
    
    For i = 2 To 5
        coll.Add r.Cells(i, 2)
        
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To 5
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 6)).Value = coll(i).Value
       
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

The error is highlighted in this code line below

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 6)).Value = coll(i).Value
```

Comment: Which value does _i_ has, when the error occurs? How many items does your collection have? (I guess _i_ is 5 and the collection does only have 4 items)

Answer (score 0):

try `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 6)).Value = coll(i,2).Value`
it may help

Answer (score 0):

This error most likely arose due to the fact that the code is trying to reach some area indirectly by the address or name in `Cells(i,6)` (see [how the first parameter is interpreted in Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.item)). Suppose you put a string "A1" into the cell `F2` which is `Cells(2, 6)`. Then the code `Range(Cells(2,6))` will substitute `Cells(2,6)` by its value and return `Range("A1")`.

I assume that this wasn't your intent. I guess that the `Cells(i,6)` are empty for `i=2 to 5` or do not contain correct range addresses. Maybe you wanted to do something like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value = coll(i).Value
```

If so, then pay attention to how the assignment of the `Collection` keys is provided, because you have another trap on your way. If you omit [declaring keys explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-visual-basic-for-applications), then they are assigned automatically starting from 1. So the next error you'll get is *Subscript out of range* in the second for-loop at `i=5`. To avoid this, declare the keys explicitly:

```
coll.Add r.Cells(i, 2), Key:=i
```

---

P.S.
If, nevertheless, you wanted to do exactly indirect access to cells, then you should check the correctness of addresses in the `F2:F5` range. I can't imagine that anything else could've caused the error you mentioned.